# Creating Unity Handles without any visible game objects at given regions

Tags: unity

I am trying to create handles without any visible game objects. The image below from a sample scene shows rects (top left rect is at position (-2, 4), size is (1, 1)) of the handles I want to appear when the mouse is hovered over the rectangular areas. So basically in a scene with no game objects I want to be able to hover over with the mouse to show the squares below as handles.

[image]

I believe the issue is most likely with the `Raycast` in `UpdateHandlePosition()`. The handles only appear when there are objects on the screen and they appear at the wrong places. Please see the relevant code below.

```
static void UpdateHandlePosition()
{
    if( Event.current == null )
    {
        return;
    }

    Vector2 mousePosition = new Vector2( Event.current.mousePosition.x, Event.current.mousePosition.y );

    Ray ray = HandleUtility.GUIPointToWorldRay( mousePosition );
    RaycastHit hit;

    if( Physics.Raycast( ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer( "Default" ) ) == true )
    {
        Vector3 offset = Vector3.zero;

        if( EditorPrefs.GetBool( "SelectBlockNextToMousePosition", true ) == true )
        {
            offset = hit.normal;
        }

        CurrentHandlePosition.x = Mathf.Floor( hit.point.x - hit.normal.x * 0.001f + offset.x );
        CurrentHandlePosition.y = Mathf.Floor( hit.point.y - hit.normal.y * 0.001f + offset.y );
        CurrentHandlePosition.z = Mathf.Floor( hit.point.z - hit.normal.z * 0.001f + offset.z );

        //CurrentHandlePosition += new Vector3( 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f );
    }
}


    static void DrawHandlesCube( Vector3 center )
{

    Vector3 p1 = center + Vector3.up * 0.5f + Vector3.right * 0.5f + Vector3.forward * 0.5f;
    Vector3 p2 = center + Vector3.up * 0.5f + Vector3.right * 0.5f - Vector3.forward * 0.5f;
    Vector3 p3 = center + Vector3.up * 0.5f - Vector3.right * 0.5f - Vector3.forward * 0.5f;
    Vector3 p4 = center + Vector3.up * 0.5f - Vector3.right * 0.5f + Vector3.forward * 0.5f;

    Vector3 p5 = center - Vector3.up * 0.5f + Vector3.right * 0.5f + Vector3.forward * 0.5f;
    Vector3 p6 = center - Vector3.up * 0.5f + Vector3.right * 0.5f - Vector3.forward * 0.5f;
    Vector3 p7 = center - Vector3.up * 0.5f - Vector3.right * 0.5f - Vector3.forward * 0.5f;
    Vector3 p8 = center - Vector3.up * 0.5f - Vector3.right * 0.5f + Vector3.forward * 0.5f;

    //You can use Handles to draw 3d objects into the SceneView. If defined properly the
    //user can even interact with the handles. For example Unitys move tool is implemented using Handles
    //However here we simply draw a cube that the 3D position the mouse is pointing to
    Handles.DrawLine( p1, p2 );
    Handles.DrawLine( p2, p3 );
    Handles.DrawLine( p3, p4 );
    Handles.DrawLine( p4, p1 );

    Handles.DrawLine( p5, p6 );
    Handles.DrawLine( p6, p7 );
    Handles.DrawLine( p7, p8 );
    Handles.DrawLine( p8, p5 );

    Handles.DrawLine( p1, p5 );
    Handles.DrawLine( p2, p6 );
    Handles.DrawLine( p3, p7 );   
    Handles.DrawLine( p4, p8 );

}
}
```

Comment: Uh. You can easily have a gameobject with a collider attached, but no renderer. That would create a zone that you can mouse-over without *drawing* anything.

Comment: @Draco18s I would like to achieve this without colliders and especially game objects, that's the main reason I want to use handles.

Comment: If you dont have a gameobject, the component is not attached to anything, and thus, will be removed by the garbage collector.

Comment: Note the difference between having a *game object* and having a *visible* game object.

Comment: Handles, in no way, help you solve your problem. You're still making a call to `Physics.Raycast` which still requires that a collider exist in the scene and a collider requires that it be attached to a game object.